# JAVA JERSEY 2.x: Toggle Logging at runtime

Tags: java, logging, jersey

I want to enable/disable logging in JERSEY programmatically.
I tried

Enable:

```
client.property ( LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY ); 
client.property ( LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT,  "INFO");
```

Disable:

```
    client.property ( LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT,  null) ;
    client.property ( LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT,  null);
```

but no luck. Logging itself works.

Does the client have to be re-created when properties change ?

Does anybody have a clue ?

Regards
Gerry

Comment: You can register providers and set properties on the WebTarget instead of the Client.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Works like a charm !